# Flow: Looks like you don't have access to this field, or the object or field API name is not valid on this Lookup component

Tags: visual-workflow

Using the (relatively) new Lightning Flow Lookup Component and I get this error
[image]

The lookup component is configured as follows:

[image]

> But the field Quote.ShipTo_Contact__c is:
>
> - Accessible to the running user
> - Spelled correctly

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is that the Field API Name (unlike Apex) is **case sensitive** for this component(!)

- API Name on object: `ShipTo_Contact__c`
- API Name configured on Lookup Component: `Shipto_Contact__c`

> Note the `ShipTo...` vs `Shipto...`

Changing the Field API Name to match the true API name (case sensitive) on the object solves the issue.